# Raspberry pi 3B+ and Beats Pill+ bluetooth speaker

Tags: audio, bluetooth, speakers

I have Raspberry pi 3B+ and bluetooth speaker Beats Pill+. I am trying to forward all audio to this speaker and use it as default. Bluetooth connection between rpi and speaker is not a problem, using `bluetoothctl` I can easily achieve it. Using this command: `aplay -D bluealsa:HCI=hci0,DEV=MAC,PROFILE=a2dp /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav` I can play test sound to the speaker but I am not able to find how to forward all sounds to this speaker (for example `espeak "test"`).

Thanks for advance

Comment: Have you tried setting your speaker as the default audio device? Is that what you want?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, I want to do this but I don't know where I can set up BT speaker as default audio device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a file *~/.asoundrc* with the following content:

```
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave {
                pcm {
                        type bluealsa
                        device <MAC>
                        profile "a2dp"
                }
        }
        hint {
                show on
                description "BEATS"
        }
}
ctl.!default {
        type bluealsa
}
```

If this does not work you could also try the following content for your *.asoundrc* file

```
defaults.bluealsa.interface "hci0"
defaults.bluealsa.profile "a2dp"
defaults.bluealsa.delay 10000
defaults.bluealsa.battery "yes"
defaults.bluealsa.device "<MAC>"

pcm.!default {
      type hw
      card 1
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

Currently I am not completely sure if you need to restart services or if it works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Volume Control (`pavucontrol` in the shell), go to the Output Devices tab and push the "Default" button in front of your Bluetooth audio device:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is only defualt audio device in output device and not bluetooth speaker.

Comment: @Matej Run `apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` and restart.

Comment: I tried to achieve this using pulseaudio but without success. Solution with alsa and .asounrc works well.