# Bluetooth headset paired and connected, but can't be selected as audio output

Tags: bluetooth, pi-4, raspbian-buster

I'm stuck getting a pretty standard A2DP Bluetooth headset to work with Raspbian Buster on an RPi 4. I successfully paired it with the RPi and can connect it via the GUI, and the buttons on the headset can control the playback in VLC for instance. However, when I select it as an audio output in Volume Control applet, the green checkmark stays on "HDMI", which is the other audio output I have.

I would like to keep using `bluealsa` (which I assume is the default on Buster) and avoid installing pulse if possible. I use the built-in BT adapter, and WiFi is disabled. AFAIK I didn't change any audio/BT-related config files.

I'm not sure which log I could provide, for a start there's that:

`hcitool con`

```
Connections:
    < ACL 00:15:01:02:DE:02 handle 12 state 1 lm MASTER AUTH ENCRYPT
```

`service bluealsa status`

```
● bluealsa.service - BluezALSA proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluealsa.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-09-23 20:18:37 CEST; 10min ago
 Main PID: 3789 (bluealsa)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 868.0K
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluealsa.service
           └─3789 /usr/bin/bluealsa

Sep 23 20:18:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started BluezALSA proxy.
Sep 23 20:19:16 raspberrypi bluealsa[3789]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: CMD: command:+CLCC, value:(null)
Sep 23 20:19:16 raspberrypi bluealsa[3789]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: SET: command:+CSRSF, value:0,0,0,1,0,0,0
```

`service bluetooth status`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-09-23 20:07:45 CEST; 10min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1007 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1007 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Sep 23 20:10:32 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.24 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Sink/1
Sep 23 20:10:33 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.25 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Sep 23 20:18:37 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.25 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Sep 23 20:18:37 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.28 path=/org/bluez/hci0/A2DP/SBC/Source/1
Sep 23 20:18:37 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Unable to get connect data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Sep 23 20:18:48 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Unable to get connect data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Sep 23 20:18:50 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Unable to get connect data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Sep 23 20:19:11 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Unable to get connect data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Sep 23 20:19:16 raspberrypi bluetoothd[1007]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

`sudo dmesg -c`

```
[  635.803532] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  635.803546] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  635.803563] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  638.100771] input: 00:15:01:02:DE:02 as /devices/virtual/input/input7
[  669.713843] input: 00:15:01:02:DE:02 as /devices/virtual/input/input8
```

Comment: Have you tried using an .asoundrc file? An example for such a file was given here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99975/raspberry-pi-3b-and-beats-pill-bluetooth-speaker/99980#99980

Comment: For those not already noticed, buster release 2019-09-26 has the following changes:
  * Switching of audio input devices added to volume plugin
  * .asoundrc (ALSA config file) now uses 'plug' values to support more devices
  * Audio Settings tool modified to integrate more closely with volume plugin to reduce duplicated code
  * Latest changes to Bluez ALSA interface integrated to improve connection to Bluetooth audio devices
  * Version 3.0.8 of VLC added
turned off (I have no confidence in this new release, so I gave up Bluetooth for this release. :))

Answer (score 1):

I ended up connecting the BT headset to my Pi using the [GuliKit audio adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000103601769.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dbQzbpw) (I got it for Nintendo Switch but it comes with a USB adapter and works with computers too). It supports sending audio to two headsets at once, and is essentially plug and play: I just plugged it into the Pi's USB port and it simply appeared in the list of audio outputs.

Answer (score -1):

***Short Answer***

I have been trying BlueZ 5.5 on Rpi3B+ stretch and Rpi4B buster for hours and so far no luck.

I use USB sound stick and VLC.

I can set audio devices using three methods,

> (1) Terminal mode Raspi-config (force to 3.5mm jack or others),
>
> (2) GUI Desktop top right corner volume icon right click (HMDI or
>   others),
>
> (3) VLC setting, clicking/selecting audio devices in Audio > Audio Device > ...

I found one method might overwrite the others.  For example, I select HDMI using Desktop top right corner volume icon, but I can still play VLC, even my HDMI monitor does not have any speaker.  So I guess VLC can select "other" or "default" as they see fit.

I am using BlueZ and not BlueAlsa, so my problem might be very different from yours.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Bluealsa is an ALSA backend for Bluez, so unless you have installed pulse, jackd or something exotic instead of Bluealsa, we are likely in the same boat.

Comment: I haven't yet managed to work bluealsa on buster lite.  Pulseaudio works pretty well, but it has issues  with sample rates not being set properly.  I've been at it for months, there just isn't a reliable way out there.  I would recommend using pulse its less headache far more advanced.  bluealsa has a lot of catching up to do